# Eclipse Android Neon: Tons of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I reinstalled 4-5 times the Eclipse Neon (Latest) and I downloaded following SDK's:

- SDK Platform API 24 Re. 1
- SDK Platform API 8 Rev. 3
- Android SDK Tools Rev. 25.1.7
- Android SDK Platform-Tools Rev. 24
- Android SDK Build-Tools Rev. 24
- Android SDK Build-Tools Rev. 23.0.3
- Google USB Driver Rev. 11

And I have JDK and JRE 1.8.0 update 92, I use Eclipse Java Neon perfectly errorless.

When I create a project, it looks like this:

[image]

And I'm getting following errors:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'zzzzf'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And it cannot resolve variable R.
After editing project properties, I get this message:

```
[2016-07-10 00:13:12 - zzzzf] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
```

Also I am getting some kind of errors that I dont remember and Eclipse says "Good news! It seems this bug is fixed on next updates. Vİsit null for further information." But when I check the updates, there are no update. -- Errors are about running the workbench.

I tried:

- Adding resource filters
- Editing eclipse.ini by adding this line before -vmargs

  -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home

Thanks for your help and giving a part of your valuable time. I am using AIDE for preparing applications and when I switch to PC, I'm busy with problems instead of Java codes...

Comment: Anything against using Android Studio?

Comment: Eclipse is [no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). You may get it to work but I'd try either a version of Eclipse from back when the plugin was supported (Mars I think) or Android Studio because that's now the officially supported IDE.

Comment: It's laggy to use Android Studio for me and I can't create a Virtual Device on it because of Intel doesn't accepts... My hardware doesn't support Intel's program.

Comment: You don't need intel's thing to run a virtual device (+ the way virtual devices run is to my knowledge unchanged between eclipse and AS). It's slower to use a non-accelerated VM but it's still possible. Android Studio should also be effectively as fast as Eclipse.

Comment: @zapl I couldn't run a VM but Android Studio's itself is laggy. But I'm downloading Android Studio again, nowhere to run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved by switching to Android Studio, because Eclipse is no longer supported by ADT. So that I am getting rid of that errors.

Comment: Under configure, you need to convert from ADT.

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 2016, I am able to create, compile and run Android projects under Eclipse Neon.

My installation details are:

- ADT Tools    23.0.7.2120684
- Eclipse Platform 4.6.1.M20160907-1200 (Eclipse Neon.1)
- Ubuntu 16.04

There are some glitches:

- LogCat and Devices views don't render well
- Previewing a layout is possible, but you have to choose Android version < 23 in the preview version dropdown

If that doesn't work, you can try [this independently maintained ADT](https://github.com/khaledev/ADT) as well. I get the same result with this ADT, so I didn't bother using it. It seems to be especially useful for those using Android NDK.

Update:
The Eclipse Foundation also maintains a fork of ADT called [AndMore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore). It works fine with Neon.

Answer (score 0):

For converting existing ADT projects to Android-Neon, 
just select "configure-->convert From ADT" from the main popup menu.

Also Neon appears to be able to profile your hardware. I was getting crashes until I simply removed the memory and GC entries from eclipse.ini

Answer (score -1):

When a project is created in Eclipse it automatically creates a folder called 
***.settings***
And files named 
***.classpath*,
*.project*,
*project.properties***

You can create a new project using the same package name and just copy the files over into this new project, rebuild it.

The more advanced, more direct and less headache approach is to find a current Eclipse project and copy the above named files over and edit them for this project.

Comment: Well, but Eclipse can't create it's own files. Anyway I just changed my IDE, topic is closed now.

Answer (score -1):

Select your android project and go to 
Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add library => Android Classpath Contanier => Next => select your project android

Then push button Finish => Apply and Ok!  and your errors is empty.

I hope help you... Good luck